# Php exception result in white page

Tags: php

Im working on product server. When an exception takes place, nothing is seen but a white screen. I expected that it would print where the error was.

Comment: Check your error logs

Comment: Show us your code John

Comment: nothing really to show... "throw new Exception('bla');" and nothing is seen on the screen. Error logs, where? I even turned on all error showings

Comment: I cant edit php.ini nor see any log... all I have is an FTP account

Comment: I did these:
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off
still no joy

Answer (score -1):

Did you enable *error reporting*? By trying:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: yea, its already done. Still a white screen

Comment: anyway, those calling returns "false" :S

Comment: error_reporting(NEWLEVEL) returns the previous level:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

so if you get "false" as its result, it means that the previous reporting level was zero